# Live Time on WP showing weirdly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display the actual time with seconds on a WordPress site, but for some reason on the minutes and seconds it shows a 3rd digit, like this:

```
5:019:014
```

Here is the script I'm using:

```
function startTime() {
var d=new Date();
var h=d.getHours();
var m=d.getMinutes();
var s=d.getSeconds();
h = h % 12;
    h= h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    var ampm=h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    m = m < 10 ? '0'+m : m;
    s = s <10 ? '0'+s: s;
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('timeis').innerHTML =" "+h+":"+m+":"+s;
}

function checkTime(i) {
var j = i;
if (i < 10) {
    j = "0" + i;
}
return j;
}

setInterval(function() {
startTime();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated version of the code which fixes the extra zero caused by the redundant time checks in `startTime()`:

**JavaScript**

```
function startTime() {
    var d=new Date();
    var h=d.getHours();
    var m=d.getMinutes();
    var s=d.getSeconds();
    h = h % 12;
    h = h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('timeis').innerHTML =" "+h+":"+m+":"+s;
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if ( i == 0 ) {
        return "00";
    }

    if ( i < 10 ) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

setInterval(function() {
    startTime();
}, 500);
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="timeis" href="#"></a>
```